# SAML2 and spring-security in weblogic 12.1.3 looses the userobject

Tags: spring-security, weblogic, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am currently trying to add support for SAML2 via Springsecurity and spring-boot in weblogic 12.1.3.

I will use the tutorial at https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample.

I have managed to generate metadata in Weblogic, but SSO doesn’t work.
It works when I run with spring boot, but not when I deploy to Weblogic 12.1.3 
What I do in the application is:

- I am navigating to my application http://localhost:7001/saml/login
- I am redirected to ssocircle.com (IdP)
- I am authenticating with my username and password at the IdP
- The IdP redirects me back to my application
- My application is throwing a NPE and forwards to an errorpage

Server output:

```
2016-11-17 09:32:13.966  INFO 12096 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger  : AuthNResponse;SUCCESS;0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;urn:dev:name:city;https://idp.ssocircle.com;email@gmail.com;;
<17.nov.2016 kl 09.32 CET> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101394> <The exception "The request content-type is not a multipart/form-data" occurred when processing getParameter or getParameterValues from a multipart value of a ServletRequest.>
2016-11-17 09:32:13.996 ERROR 12096 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter     : Forwarding to error page from request [/landing] due to exception [null]

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
  at com.vdenotaris.spring.boot.security.saml.web.core.CurrentUserHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(CurrentUserHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:47) ~[_wl_cls_gen.jar:na]
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at com.package.IndexForwardFilter.doFilter(IndexForwardFilter.java:31) ~[_wl_cls_gen.jar:na]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:94) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:112) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]

  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]

  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:185) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.doFilter(SAMLEntryPoint.java:103) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLDiscovery.doFilter(SAMLDiscovery.java:137) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter.doFilter(MetadataDisplayFilter.java:84) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.processLogout(SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.java:206) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.doFilter(SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.java:104) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter.processLogout(SAMLLogoutFilter.java:164) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter.doFilter(SAMLLogoutFilter.java:106) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]

  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]

  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120) [com.oracle.css.weblogic.security.wls_7.1.0.0.jar:CSS 7.1 0.0]
  at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
```

I don’t know if the warning “The request content-type is not a multipart/form-data" occurred when processing getParameter or getParameterValues from a multipart value of a ServletRequest” has anything to do with the nullpointerexception

The nullpointerexception is thrown in CurrentUserHandlerMethodArgumentResolver because webRequest.getUserPrincipal() returns null.

```
public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter,
        ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest,
        WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
    if (this.supportsParameter(methodParameter)) {
        Principal principal = (Principal) webRequest.getUserPrincipal();
        return (User) ((Authentication) principal).getPrincipal();
    } else {
        return WebArgumentResolver.UNRESOLVED;
    }
}
```

This is the webRequest in tomcat, note that the user object is present:
[image]
This is the webRequest in Weblogic, note that the user object is missing:
[image]

Any Ideas or tip would be appreciated.

The only thing I had to do in weblogic in addition to code in the tutorial is to add this in weblogic.xml to insist weblogic to usy my opensaml library:

```
<weblogic-web-app>
  <weblogic-version>12.1.3</weblogic-version>
  <context-root>/</context-root>
  <container-descriptor>
  <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
  <prefer-application-packages>
   <package-name>org.opensaml.*</package-name>
   ..
```

Regards Geir Nipe

Comment: It turned out that Weblogic lost the securityContext. The solution was to add a custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler and use it.

Comment: could you detail your answer please?